# How to use "to a great degree" to modify comparatives?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I want to express "Method A is far more efficient than method B." Are the following five sentences correct or not? And why?

1. Method A is to a great degree more efficient than method B.
2. Method A is to a greater degree more efficient than method B.
3. Method A is to a greater degree efficient than method B.
4. Method A, to a greater degree than method B, is efficient.
5. Method A, to a greater degree than method B, is more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To a greater degree* means the same as *more*, so it is wrong to use both in the same sentence as in (2) and (5).

Sentence (1) is acceptable; the word order in (3) and (4) is awkward. I would prefer

> Method A is efficient to a greater degree than Method B.

But what's wrong with *far more efficient*?

Comment: Your rewrite discards intensifier ***far** [more]* from OP's original "I want to say". I don't like your version anyway, but *Method A is efficient to a far greater degree than Method B* doesn't sound remotely idiomatic. I think the only sensible advice for OP is he should forget about "greater degrees" and stick with ***far more efficient***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I left out **far** because it isn't included in OP's example sentences.

Comment: But you included it in ***far more efficient***.